# Не работает подсветка синтаксиса в Jupyter Notebook, или какая комбинация клавишь позволяет это сделать?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Просматривая видео в котором авторы используют Jupyter Notebook, обратил внимание, что у них работает подсветка синтаксиса как в IDE.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я же, долгое время думал, что такое подсветки в Notebook попросту нету.

Попробовав на 3ех разных компьютерах различные варианты ноутбука (в Анаконде и отдельный) так и не получилось добиться подсветки синтаксиса. Результы поиска горячих клавиш ничего не принесли. Надежда на stackoverflow.com!

Пусть вопрос покажется глупым, но оочень хочется что бы работала подсветка синтаксиса.

Версия ноутбука 5.6.0

Comment: Нужно было просто нажать TAB. Вопрос удалять не буду, вдруг кому то будет полезен

Comment: Напишите это как ответ, может быть, что получите за него и баллы.